# oneside option gives error

Tags: templates, double-sided

I'm writing my thesis and I have a problem: if I put `twoside` in the options I obtain no error. I need to print `oneside` so I put the option `oneside` but I obtained hundreds errors.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final]{tesi}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %English
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %ITALIANO
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}


\input{inc-commands.tex}

\input{inc-formattazione.tex}

\makeindex

\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollario} 
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione} 

\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}[chapter] 

\theoremstyle{remark} 
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione} 
%===========================================================================================
\begin{document}
\singlespacing
\input{inc-frontespizio.tex}

\onehalfspacing
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\doublespacing
\pagestyle{headings}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{testo-tesi.tex}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}
\singlespacing
\listoffigures\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\listoftables\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\begin{appendices}
%\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices
% Appendix A
\input{./Appendices/AppendixA}  % Appendix Title
% Appendix B
\input{./Appendices/AppendixB} % Appendix Title
\end{appendices}
\begin{thebibliography}{100} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 

\end{thebibliography} 

\end{document}
```

this is the thesis class:

```
%% 
%% This file was generated from file(s) of the LaTeX base system.
%% --------------------------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This file has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%% 
%% This file may only be distributed together with a copy of the LaTeX
%% base system. You may however distribute the LaTeX base system without
%% such generated files.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the LaTeX base distribution is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'. See also `legal.txt' for additional
%% information.
%% 
%% The list of derived (unpacked) files belonging to the distribution
%% and covered by LPPL is defined by the unpacking scripts (with
%% extension .ins) which are part of the distribution.
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{tesi}
              [2007/11/24 
  Standard LaTeX document class]
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagetrue
\newif\if@openright
\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {210mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {148mm}}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {250mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {176mm}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {14in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {10.5in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {7.25in}}
\DeclareOption{landscape}
   {\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}}
\fi
\if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\@titlepagetrue}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{notitlepage}{\@titlepagefalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility
\@openrighttrue
\else
\DeclareOption{openright}{\@openrighttrue}
\DeclareOption{openany}{\@openrightfalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
\DeclareOption{leqno}{\input{leqno.clo}}
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{%
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
   \renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
      \listparindent \itemindent
      \parsep \z@
      }%
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}}%
}
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,final,openright}
\ProcessOptions
\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo}
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}
\if@twoside
  \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\leftmark}\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            CAP. \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            CAP. \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        ##1}}}}
\else
  \def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
             CAP. \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\fi
\def\ps@myheadings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    }
  \if@titlepage
  \newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\else
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
\newcommand*\chaptermark[1]{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {chapter}
\newcounter {section}[chapter]
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand \thechapter {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection .\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\newcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
              \if@twoside
               \if@openright
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \newpage
               \fi
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
\fi
\leftmargin  \leftmargini
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {1em}
\fi
\setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
\setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
\addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}
\@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
\@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
\@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty
\renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
\newenvironment{description}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries #1}
\newenvironment{verse}
               {\let\\\@centercr
                \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
                        \itemindent   -1.5em%
                        \listparindent\itemindent
                        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
                        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\newenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\if@compatibility
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \cleardoublepage
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\z@
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
    }
\else
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \cleardoublepage
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\@ne
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
     \if@twoside\else
        \setcounter{page}\@ne
     \fi
    }
\fi
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
\skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
\@addtoreset {equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand\theequation
  {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@equation}
\newcounter{figure}[chapter]
\renewcommand \thefigure
     {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure }
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
\newenvironment{figure}
               {\@float{figure}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{figure*}
               {\@dblfloat{figure}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newcounter{table}[chapter]
\renewcommand \thetable
     {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{\tablename\nobreakspace\thetable}
\newenvironment{table}
               {\@float{table}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{table*}
               {\@dblfloat{table}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newlength\abovecaptionskip
\newlength\belowcaptionskip
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{2.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand\listoftables{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\let\l@table\l@figure
\newdimen\bibindent
\setlength\bibindent{1.5em}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\let\@openbib@code\@empty
\newenvironment{theindex}
               {\if@twocolumn
                  \@restonecolfalse
                \else
                  \@restonecoltrue
                \fi
                \twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}]%
                \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                        {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
                \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
                \columnseprule \z@
                \columnsep 35\p@
                \let\item\@idxitem}
               {\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
\newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@}
\newcommand\subitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{20\p@}}
\newcommand\subsubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{30\p@}}
\newcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus3\p@\relax}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\newcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\newcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\newcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
\newcommand\indexname{Index}
\newcommand\figurename{Figure}
\newcommand\tablename{Table}
\newcommand\partname{Part}
\newcommand\chaptername{Chapter}
\newcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
\setlength\columnsep{10\p@}
\setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\if@twoside
\else
  \raggedbottom
\fi
\if@twocolumn
  \twocolumn
  \sloppy
  \flushbottom
\else
  \onecolumn
\fi
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `book.cls'.
```

Comment: You example won't compile. You are using a custom made document class `tesi`. Also you have multiple `input` commands that refer to files on your system and others do not have access to.

Comment: btw if you just want to print on one side of the paper (for reviewers), you can give that setting on the printer. instead of changing it in the `tex` file.

Comment: mythealias you will know that the twoside option sligthly move the page on the right or on the lelf, so the printer option is useless.I put the tesi.cls file, it is a modified version of book.cls. please give me some key idea

Comment: I believe that if you don't specify `twoside` nor `oneside`, the effect will be `oneside`, so I think you can simply omit the option and everything will be fine for you.

Comment: @tohecz I tried your way but it doesn't work. Please help me, it is fundamental I solve it today!

Comment: @user1783116 at this point it is beyond my current knowledge of TeX. You may want to try and provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that others can compile it and reproduce the error. You can also paste relevant errors. They should be in the `.log` file.

Comment: Since the code of `tesi.cls` seems to be derived from the standard `book` class, have you tried to use the latter instead? Additionally I would recommend contacting the class author, ...although his/her name is absent from the poorly commented source code.

Comment: I added another possible solution to by answer, you can look at it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a missing `\fi` in the class file: here's how it should be (with line numbers to better show where the code is missing

```
136 \if@twoside
137   \def\ps@headings{%
138       \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
139       \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
140       \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\leftmark}\hfil\thepage}%
141       \let\@mkboth\markboth
142     \def\chaptermark##1{%
143       \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
144         \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
145           \if@mainmatter
146             CAP. \thechapter. \ %
147           \fi
148         \fi
149         ##1}}{}}%
150     \def\sectionmark##1{%
151       \markright {{%
152         \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
153           \if@mainmatter
154             CAP. \thechapter. \ %
155           \fi
156         \fi % <---- MISSING IN THE ORIGINAL
157         ##1}}}}
158 \else
```

---

A comment. The provided class, besides having a bad error in it, doesn't do much different from the standard `book` class: only a few (disputable) changes to the headers, that could be more easily made with a judicious use of `fancyhdr`.

The fact that the changes are not documented is a reason for *not* using it, unless you are forced to by some rule.

Comment: thank you so much, the problem was the \fi missing. Great!!!

Comment: My friend gave me the file I've used. Because of the lack of time, I needed to have a working file so I uses it. From now on I will change it. Thx